# Can't get elasticsearch range query to work

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elements mapped as the following

```
"metadata": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "PublicationDate": {
                            "type": "date",
                            "format": "yyyy-M-d" 
                        },
```

which doesn't seem to cause any problem, and content in those elements look like the following

```
"metadata":{"PublicationDate":"2019-7-1"}}
```

So I expected that when I did a range query like the following

```
must": {
     "range" : {
         "metadata.PublicationDate" : {
            "gte": "2011-07-01",
            "lte": "2020-07-01"
          }
      }

}
```

that it would work as all my documets are in between those two ranges, but it does not work. Do I need to show more of the query or is there something here I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `metadata` field is `nested`, so you have to query it with a `nested` query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

So, your query needs to be

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "metadata",
            "query": {
                "range": {
                    "metadata.PublicationDate": {
                        "gte": "2011-07-01",
                        "lte": "2020-07-01"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```